# Correct Syntax for SQLite with Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I already know the issue is this line of syntax for the program I am running Python's tKinter with SQLite. Can someone please correct this line of syntax? If anyone can point me to the right answer if it is already solved, please let me know I couldn't find the right answer to it.

`c.execute("DELETE FROM kvmTable WHERE kvm=kvm)", {"kvm": rmName.get()} )`

Comment: Are you getting a SQL syntax error or a python syntax error? The unbalance paren in the SQL could be problematic.

Comment: Except for the erroneous `)` in the end of the query, when using named parameters you need to have a semicolon before the placeholder: `c.execute("DELETE FROM kvmTable WHERE kvm=:kvm", {"kvm": rmName.get()} )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `)` at the end of your query.

If you want to use named placeholders, you're missing a colon - do (as @DeepSpace said)

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM kvmTable WHERE kvm=:kvm", {"kvm": rmName.get()})
```

or to use `?` placeholders,

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM kvmTable WHERE kvm=?", (rmName.get(),))
```

Comment: In this (rare, unfortunately) case OP actually tried to use a parametrized query :) , just with a dictionary instead of a tuple. They just forgot a semicolon: `c.execute("DELETE FROM kvmTable WHERE kvm=:kvm", {"kvm": rmName.get()} )`

Comment: @DeepSpace Ah right, I forgot Sqlite supports named placeholders too! Will amend.

Comment: That may very well have fixed the issue, however I am seeing a new error but I think it is unrelated. `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: kvm`